# PHP: Returning a value without terminating script execution?

Tags: php, return

Is there a way to return data using PHP without the return() terminating script execution?

Comment: `return` doesn't terminate script execution, it exits the function. If you are thinking of getting a value mid-way into the function and load it into the part of code that called that particular function, then no - it's not possible and it's pointless.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: Since when did `return` ever terminate script execution?

Comment: try `echo`ing from the middle of this function

Comment: @BoltClock: probably when you use it outside of a function ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock: `If called from within a function, the return() statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return() will also end the execution of an eval() statement or script file.`

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, than GLOBALS could help...

Comment: You might be trying to do a little too much in a single function. Take a look at what you're trying to do, does it serve a single function? Perhaps two functions would serve you better: `getWhatINeed()`, and `useItToDoSomething()`; Functions should be small/re-usable, helps with writing less code.

Comment: @leo Globals? could you clarify?

Comment: If what you really want to do is return more than one value from the function, you can return an array of values.  When compared to globals, the downside is that you won't have access to the values until the function has returned them.  Honestly, chances are that if you need to consider using globals, then there is probably a better way to structure your code, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not, `return`'s point is to *return* a value from a function.
You can however store the return value temporarily and return it at the end

```
function myFunc() {
    $retValue = "";
    //doe some stuff and at some point have $retValue = aValue
    return $retValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourval = what_you_want_to_return();
.... more stuff...
return $yourval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem another way:

If you have the function:

```
function myFunction ( $input )
{
    $var1 = $input + 5;
    $var2 = $input + 10;

    $GLOBALS['var1'] = $var1;
    $GLOBALS['var2'] = $var2;

    return null;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
myFunction(5);
echo $GLOBALS['var1'];
echo $GLOBALS['var2'];
```

But please note that this is just a solution for you, if couldn't return an array instead, because this could have conflicts with some third party libraries if the use the same key of `$GLOBALS`.